# Unquote arguments in rlang::new_function (for function factory)

Tags: r, rlang

I would like to specify a custom argument for a function created via `rlang::new_function`. For this I need to pass an argument to the `args`-argument of `new_function`.

I assume the `named_arg` should be quoted/ unquoted. This is what I have tried so far:

```r
library(rlang)

function_factory <- function(named_arg) {

  new_function(
    exprs(named_arg =,... = ),
    expr(print("hello world")),
    caller_env()
  )
}

fun1 <- function_factory(arg1)
fun1

#> function (named_arg, ...) 
#> print("hello world")
```

The desired output would be:

```r
#> function (arg1, ...) 
#> print("hello world")
```

Below is one approach I have tried, but didn't work:

```r
function_factory <- function(named_arg) {
  named_arg_quo <- enquo(named_arg)

  new_function(
    exprs(!!named_arg_quo =,... = ),
    expr(print("hello world")),
    caller_env()
  )
}
#> Error: <text>:21:27: unexpected '='
#> 20:   new_function(
#> 21:     exprs(!!named_arg_quo =
#>                               ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `substitute` to grab the unquoted argument and change the `names` of the 'exprs`

```
function_factory <- function(named_arg) {

  nm1 <- deparse(substitute(named_arg))
  exp1 <- exprs(named_arg =,... = )
  names(exp1)[1] <- nm1
  new_function(
     exp1,
     expr(print("hello world")),
     caller_env()
   )

}

function_factory(arg1)
#function (arg1, ...) 
#print("hello world")
```

---

In case, we are using `rlang`, then convert to string with `quo_name`

```
library(rlang)
function_factory <- function(named_arg) {

  nm1 <- quo_name(enquo(named_arg))
  exp1 <- exprs(named_arg =,... = )
  names(exp1)[1] <- nm1
  new_function(
     exp1,
     expr(print("hello world")),
     caller_env()
   )

}

function_factory(arg1)
#function (arg1, ...) 
#print("hello world")
```

Comment: I like the solution, because it works. ;-)
I'd rather avoid tinkering with the names of the list of expression afterwards, though. I tried `exprs(!!named_arg :=, ..., .unquote_names = FALSE)`, but it dindn't work. So how could one unquote within exprs?